# dc.js dimension filter updates all charts

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

This is my data:

```
var data = [
{"date":"04/03/2020","quarter":"q1","fuente":"Periódico Victoria","titulo":"¡Otro feminicidio! Ahora es Hannia, tenía 16 años","tipo":"historia","popularidad":12,"relevancia":13,"ubicacion":"Victoria, Tamahulipas","url":"https://periodicovictoria.mx/mexico-y-el-mundo/otro-feminicidio-ahora-es-hannia-tenia-16-anos/","medios":80,"twitter":200},
{"date":"03/03/2020","quarter":"q1","fuente":"El Imparcial","titulo":"Marciano abusó sexualmente y asesinó a una niña de 9 años; le dan prisión vitalicia","tipo":"historia","popularidad":40,"relevancia":12,"ubicacion":"Chalco, Estado de México","url":"http://www.elimparcial.com/mexico/Marciano-abuso-sexualmente-y-asesino-a-una-nina-de-9-anos-le-dan-prision-vitalicia-20200225-0079.html","medios":90,"twitter":210},
{"date":"02/03/2020","quarter":"q1","fuente":"El Siglo de Torreón","titulo":"Feminicida acudió al funeral de su víctima en Baja California","tipo":"historia","popularidad":55,"relevancia":12,"ubicacion":"Torreòn, Coahuila","url":"https://www.elsiglodetorreon.com.mx/noticia/1677021.feminicida-acudio-al-funeral-de-su-victima-en-baja-california.html","medios":120,"twitter":180}
```

As you can see there is a field "tipo" which indicates if data corresponds to a tweet, a media story, or a confirmed case of a female homicide.

I have made three different bubble charts in dcjs. Right now each bubble chart shows all data, but I want each chart to show tweets, stories or confirmed cases respectively.

The problem is that when I apply a filter to each dimension as in:

```
const dateDimension3 = ndx.dimension(d => d.tipo);
dateDimension3.filter("tweet")
```

all charts update to show only the "tweet" type, even though each chart has a different dimension

This is my codepen: https://codepen.io/mdurazob/pen/XWbYyma

This is how it actually looks: https://mdurazob.github.io/feminicidio/plataformafeminicidio.html

Comment: Hi Manuel, [dc.js](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/)'s filtering feature (powered by a library called crossfilter) is designed to synchronize filtering across charts. Perhaps you want to use something else than the function `.filter`.

Comment: The codepen does not work, and the other linked website does not show any filter  on `tipo`. Please update the sample code to clarify what the problem is, as described in [these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: can you provide an example on how to filter correctly across three bubble charts?

Comment: I am not sure how well dc.js / crossfilter is going to work if the data is not shared between the charts. These tools rely on each chart filtering a subset of the data, and then each chart is drawn on an aggregation of the data. If there is no common subset then they won't have any effect on each other. That said, to get this working you could write your group aggregation functions to count rows that don't match as zero, e.g. `historiaGroup = dim.group().reduceSum(d => d.tipo === 'historia' ? 1 : 0)`

Comment: Typically the chart will call `.filter()` in response to a change in the selection. This will affect the data seen by other groups. You need to use custom reductions or [fake groups](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups) to affect what individual charts will draw.